# What's the difference between [cassette-tape] and [magnetic-tape]?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tag-synonyms

[cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape), 67 questions:

> For questions about audio cassette tape, as used for computer data storage.

> Many 1970s-era personal computers used audio cassettes for data storage. Some early software was sold and distributed on cassette.

[magnetic-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnetic-tape), 24 questions:

> for questions about the magnetic tape storage format

> Magnetic tape data storage is a system for storing digital information on magnetic tape using digital recording.

There are 5 questions with both tags.

Questions about [floppy-disk](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floppy-disk)s seem to use [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape) and [magnetic-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnetic-tape) interchangeably: 3 and 5, respectively. A quick survey of the [15 most recent questions with these tags](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnetic-tape%2bor%2bcassette-tape?tab=newest&pagesize=15):

- [What tape format did the Nintendo Famicom Data Recorder use?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/24535/278)
  Guessed: [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape) [file-format](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-format)
  Actual: [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape) [file-format](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-format) [famicom](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/famicom)
- [Which software was the first to use copy protection?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/24481/278)
  Guessed: [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape)
  Actual: [history](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) [floppy-disk](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floppy-disk) [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape) [copy-protection](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copy-protection)
- [Does lossy audio compression damage datasette data?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/24209/278)
  Guessed: [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape)
  Actual: [commodore-64](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commodore-64) [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape) [tape-image](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tape-image)
- [Could visual inspection of the magnetic disk be used to detect the quality (or damages) of a floppy disk?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/23784/278)
  Guessed: [magnetic-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnetic-tape) [floppy-disk](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floppy-disk)
  Actual: [floppy-disk](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floppy-disk) [magnetic-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnetic-tape)
- [Why are the magnetic floppy disk drives (FDD) heads not frictionless?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/23730/278)
  Guessed: [magnetic-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnetic-tape) [floppy-disk](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floppy-disk)
  Actual: [floppy-disk](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floppy-disk) [floppy-drive](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floppy-drive) [design-choices](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design-choices) [magnetic-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnetic-tape)
- [What information could be recovered from visualized magnetic information?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/23720/278)
  Guessed: [magnetic-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnetic-tape) [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape)
  Actual: [floppy-disk](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floppy-disk) [storage](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storage) [magnetic-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnetic-tape)
- [How does a floppy drive identify the first and last sectors and tracks?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/23714/278)
  Guessed: [magnetic-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnetic-tape)
  Actual: [floppy-disk](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floppy-disk) [floppy-drive](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floppy-drive) [storage](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storage) [magnetic-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnetic-tape)
- [What is the effect of direct exposure of the magnetic disk of a floppy to ultraviolet (UV) light?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/23586/278)
  Guessed: [magnetic-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnetic-tape) [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape) [floppy-disk](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floppy-disk)
  Actual: [floppy-disk](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floppy-disk) [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape) [storage](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storage) [restoration](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restoration) [magnetic-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnetic-tape)
- [Definitive list of music bands/groups that included computer programs on their analogue audio music physical media releases (LPs, singles)](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/23506/278)
  Guessed: [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape)
  Actual: [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape) [storage](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storage) [application-program](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application-program) [multimedia](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multimedia) [kansas-city](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kansas-city)
- [How did the Commodore 64 show a picture while reading cassette?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/22269/278)
  Guessed: [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape) [commodore-64](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commodore-64)
  Actual: [commodore-64](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commodore-64) [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape)
- [Audio cassettes on TI-99](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/22266/278)
  Guessed: [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape)
  Actual: [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape) [ti-99](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ti-99)
- [Why Kansas City Standard (KCS/CUTS) differs from Bell 103/202/212 modem protocol?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/22169/278)
  Guessed: [magnetic-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnetic-tape) [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape)
  Actual: [history](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape) [storage](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storage) [modern](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modern) [kansas-city](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kansas-city)
- [Cheapest way to store and load small dataset in the 80s?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/22132/278)
  Guessed: [magnetic-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnetic-tape)
  Actual: [game-cartridge](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-cartridge) [8-bit-microcomputers](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/8-bit-microcomputers) [storage](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storage) [magnetic-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnetic-tape) [home-computers](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-computers)
- [Compression techniques used in old ZX Spectrum tapes](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/20193/278)
  Guessed: [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape)
  Actual: [zx-spectrum](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zx-spectrum) [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape) [compression](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compression)
- [How did games written for tape-based BBC micro, get officially and unofficially ported to disk, bearing in mind extra workspace needed by DFS ROM?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/19515/278)
  Guessed: [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape)
  Actual: [floppy-disk](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floppy-disk) [memory-layout](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory-layout) [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape) [bbc-micro](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bbc-micro) [compatibility](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compatibility)

| [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape) | has it | hasn't |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I guessed yes | 10 | 1 |
| I guessed no | 0 | 4 |

| [magnetic-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnetic-tape) | has it | hasn't |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I guessed yes | 6 | 1 |
| I guessed no | 0 | 8 |

While I mostly guessed right, my procedure for guessing looked like:

- If it says "cassette", it's [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape).
- If it says "magnetic", it's [magnetic-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnetic-tape).
- If it mentions a home computer or games console (other than the PC), it's [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape).
- If it mentions low-level details (e.g. sectors and tracks), it's [magnetic-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnetic-tape).

With the exception of [kansas-city](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kansas-city) questions, all four of which are [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape), this distinction feels arbitrary to me. Where the distinction *matters*, [kansas-city](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kansas-city) makes it.

Is the distinction between these tags useful?

- If so, we should update the tag wikis to explain it.
- If not, what should the combined tag be called?

Comment: I suppose [tag:cassette-tape] would not be appropriate for open-reel tape drives…

Comment: @user3840170 There's a bit of a difference, then. Am I right in saying that [tag:cassette-tape] is a _subset_ of [tag:magnetic-tape]?

Answer (score 5):

It seems the tags are simply being misused.

Cassette tape refers to the Philips Compact Cassette standard form factor used for audio etc.  That should remain.

Magnetic tape could cover anything from Sinclair Phloopy tapes to the great spinning reels seen on 60s mainframes.  Using both tags on a post is superfluous.

You also have Cartridge Tapes which could cover Dec's TKxx range or Iomega's PC offerings.  They deserve their own tag.

Using a tape tag and a floppy tag on rhe same question is just plain wrong, unless the question asks about some comparison.

The distinction between the tags is not only useful, it is essential.

I would suggest a tag cleanup exercise.  The tags we have work if correctly applied.  We may need to create one or two more tags but not necessarily.  I see no need for synonyms at this time.

Comment: How would you suggest improving the tag wikis?

Comment: @wizzwizz4, I would suggest expanding them, adding cross-references.  I'm hospital visiting for a few days with only sporadic phone access, but I'll happily have a go at them later in the week.

Comment: Isn't VHS a cassette tape?

Comment: @user3840170:  Yes, so are the Olympus microcassettes used in dictaphones and old Epson handheld computers.  We have to be careful with wording.

Comment: I would consider micro-cassettes the cassette tape, but not Video-cassettes, or other cassette based tape drives. In the end the separation is more between home computer  type media (cassette-tape) and magnetic tape storage in general (magnetic-tape).